# Shorting the Output of a voltage regulator

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, short-circuit, testing, power-output-stage

I am using this [Buck Converter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54260-q1.pdf?ts=1594349573367&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Input Voltage Range - 8-16V

Output Voltage - 5V

Load Current - 550mA

This 5V is the power supply (Vcc) to the mentioned IC loads :
[Microcontroller](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC5606S.pdf) , [LED Driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slis142d/slis142d.pdf?ts=1594349678750&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) , 2x [CAN Transceivers](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/TJA1044.pdf) & [5V to 3.3V LDO](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/linear_regulator/buxxsd5wg-e.pdf)

My questions :

1. I want to check what would happen if I short the Output of the 5V Buck Regulator for a fraction of second. (a) How to perform and check what would happen if I short circuit the output of the regulator while it is still connected to the Vcc of the above mentioned IC Loads? Won't those ICs get damaged if I short the Output of the 5V?

Objective of the Short Circuit test : Just want to understand what would happen if the buck regulator is shorted for some reason in my board. Is there a recommended time duration for how long the output can be shorted?

2. Is it recommended to perform the short circuiting of the Buck Regulator output when it is connected to the above IC Loads?
3. Usually do the buck converters have short circuit protection? By this, do they mean that if the regulator output is shorted, the IC does not provide a lot of output current (so a to protect the underlying loads and the PCB)? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Shorting the buck regulator output to GND probably will not damage any of the downstream components.  BUT ...
2. It NEVER is "recommended" to apply a dead short to the output of a switching regulator.  Some linear regulators, such as in lab or bench supplies, use this technique to set the output current limit, but your circuit is not that.
3. This part has an internal switch transistor rating of 2.5 A.  It has internal overcurrent monitoring and protection.  The threshold value is very loosely specified, but the minimum value is 3.1 A.

Comment: thank you for the answer. 1.  Just curious to understand, how does the shorting of the regulator output does not affect any downstream components? In the PCB, when we short the 5V, the 5V Vcc and the ground of the downstream components are also shorted right. Since current takes a path of least resistance, a huge current might flow through the Vcc and the ground planes on the PCB which might heat up the downstream ICs and may cause it to get damaged, right? Please explain. I am confused on how the downstream components might not affected?

Comment: 2. When you say , "Some linear regulators, such as in lab or bench supplies' - do you mean, Linear regulator ICs or bench power supplies like, for eg, say, GPC-3030D?

Comment: 3. I tried searching, the internal switch transistor which you mentioned in the Buck regulator datasheet. I was not able to find it. Could you please tell me where you figured it out and how it might help with the short circuit protection?

Comment: when you short VCC to GROUND the current flows though the conductors that form the short circuit,  the ICs down stream do not form part of the short circuit, so they will not see this current.  if the ICs are driving capacitive loads they may see capacitor discharge currents through the protection diodes on the outputs that are connected to the capacitive loads. (eg your LDO is probablty driving a capacitive load)

Comment: Can someone help me with the answers for these comments?

Comment: 2.  Bench supplies.  3.  The datasheet you linked, page 12, 7.2, right side.  Above and to the left of pin 1 is a circle around a wire called Current Sense.  This is some unknown internal circuit that monitors the drain current of the main output FET and modifies the PWM timing.

Comment: 1.  Huge transient currents happen only when there is huge energy storage.  Hundreds or even thousands of uF splattered around a pc board do not total up to much charge storage.  Also, there are inducances all over the place (and inside the capacitors) that limit the risetime of the current, and this greatly affects the peak value.  Components that routinely have a large capacitance connected to an input or output pin, such as a linear regulator like the LM317, come with recommended circuits for dealing with possible reverse current consequences.  This is what Jasen is referring to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, on conclusion, I can short the output 5V of the regulator, right? And is there like a thumb rule on how much time I should short the output terminals and what is the most important parameter to look during the shorted time - is it the maximum current between the 5V and ground or is it a different parameter that I have to look for?

Comment: The correct amount of time is *do not do this*.  The internal short-circuit protection is not an operational feature - it is there to prevent a disaster.  There is no spec for how long or how often.  Why is it so important to do this?

Comment: I am just curious to understand what would happen if it is done. And in general, I want to know if engineers test dc-dc regulators , would they perform this test? If they perform, how they do it? Just wanted to understand all these. That's why I asked this question